# SecureString could not be created (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, securestring

when I try to build SecureString there is no in code error, but upon building it writes: CS0246: The Type or Namespace Name  Could Not be Found. I have assembly for System.Security in dnx 4.5.1 and the library is linked at the top of the page.
Can you help me out?

[image: Screen]

Comment: did you added the reference in your reference folder?

Comment: I have "System.Security" in "References -> DNX 4.5.1 -> FrameworkAssemblies" on the right. Is this what you asked? I am new to that